# C# How to add value in comboBox text?

Tags: c#, text, combobox

how do you add an integer value for the existing combo box? Example: There are already 5 text values in the combo box "Access","create".... But How can I add an integer value to these text? Example "Access" = 1 , "Create" = 2?

Please advise on the codes! Thanks!

The codes:

```
        comboBoxFilter.Items.Add("Access");
        comboBoxFilter.Items.Add("Create");
        comboBoxFilter.Items.Add("Delete");
        comboBoxFilter.Items.Add("Modify");
        comboBoxFilter.Items.Add("All");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the numbers before hand, you can do something like this:

```
comboBoxFilter.Items.Add("Access = 1");
```

If you do not, you can have something like this:

```
comboBoxFilter.Items.Add("Access = " + numbers.ToString());
```

The above should give you something like this in the combo box: `Access = <someNumber>`

If you strictly want "Access" =  do something like:

```
comboBoxFilter.Items.Add("\"Access\" = 1");
```

or

```
comboBoxFilter.Items.Add("\"Access\" = " + numbers.ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you create a class:

```
public class Permission
{
    public Int32 Index { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

And fill your `ComboBox` like following:

```
List<Permission> permissions = new List<Permission>() { 
    new Permission(){ Index = 1, Value ="Access" },
    new Permission(){ Index = 2, Value ="Create" },
    new Permission(){ Index = 3, Value ="Delete" },
    new Permission(){ Index = 4, Value ="Modify" },
    new Permission(){ Index = 5, Value ="All" },
};

comboBoxFilter.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBoxFilter.DataSource = permissions;
```

With the code above, you can access the integer value using following code:

```
(comboBoxFilter.SelectedItem as Permission).Index
```

Comment: This is the only valid solution. Unfortunately, it's to big task for a simple wants ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ListItem approach where you would have to use

```
comboBoxFilter.Items.Add(new ListItem("Access", "1"));
comboBoxFilter.Items.Add(new ListItem("Create", "2"));
comboBoxFilter.Items.Add(new ListItem("Delete", "3"));
comboBoxFilter.Items.Add(new ListItem("Modify", "4"));
comboBoxFilter.Items.Add(new ListItem("All", "5"));
```

Keep in mind though that both the `Value` and `Text` section of the ListItem are strings.

*P.S. You did not specify if this was a winforms or webforms, so I assumed web. If it is Winforms this does not apply*

Comment: And also keep in mind ListItem is for web http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I just edited just seconds after I posted, in case athgap needs a a win solution.